# How correctly implement a SparseArray to store a custom object on each instance of a ViewPager? Android Development - Java

Tags: java, android, object, android-viewpager, parcelable

First I'd like to thank you all for your time and help, in advanced. My question is probably a basic, and silly one. However, I am a beginner and I guess this is a good place to learn!

So, I have a custom object called Question, and it is described in Question.java; It looks like this:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;





public class Question implements Parcelable{
    String mark;
    String total;
    String worth;

public Question(String amark, String atotal, String aworth ) {
    mark = amark;
    total = atotal;
    worth = aworth;

}

public Question(Parcel in) {

        mark = in .readString();
        total = in .readString();
        worth = in .readString();


}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in ) {

    mark = in .readString();
    total = in .readString();
    worth = in .readString();

}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(mark);
    dest.writeString(total);
    dest.writeString(worth);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Question> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Question>() {
    public Question createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Question(in);
    }

    public Question[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Question[size];
    }
};
}
```

Now I am creating a user defined number of forms to collect information from a user. So I am trying to create a SparseArray, which each entry contains a Question object (so I can pass all this information to another activity for implementation). Now I have all the passing working, as it seems. However, because each time my UserFragment.java is opened (each 'form' is an instance of UserFragment, controlled by FirstFragment.java which is the activity creating the view pages), basically I create a new SparseList of question because my UserFragment.java looks like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserFragment extends Fragment {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_avgcalcform,
                container, false);

        final int pagetotal = getArguments().getInt("size");


           TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.avg_testtv);
           tv.setText(String.valueOf(getArguments().getInt("page_position")));
         String Text;
         if(pagetotal==getArguments().getInt("page_position")){
             Text = "Submit";
         } else
         Text = "next";  

        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setText(Text);
        b.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){

               public void onClick(View v){
                   //Extracting the information from the user input forms! NOTE:NEED TO ADD ERROR CHECKING
                final EditText markc = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextASSMARK);
                final EditText marktotc = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextASSTOT);
                final EditText assvalc = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextASSWORTH);
                   //Converting from INFO string to int
                   double currentassmark = Double.parseDouble(markc.getText().toString());
                   double currentassworth = Double.parseDouble(marktotc.getText().toString());
                   double currentassval = Double.parseDouble(assvalc.getText().toString());
                   // Determining the current viewnumber (or form number) the user is currently on.
                   int currentviewnum =  ((FirstFragment) getActivity()).getPager().getCurrentItem();

                   saveData(new Question(markc.getText().toString(),marktotc.getText().toString(),assvalc.getText().toString()),currentviewnum);
                   ((FirstFragment) getActivity()).getPager().setCurrentItem(currentviewnum+1);
                   double totalpercentage =(double)((currentassmark/currentassworth)*currentassval);
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   int currentpagenumber =  getArguments().getInt("page_position");
                   String currentpage = String.valueOf(currentpagenumber);
                   //bundle.putDouble(currentpage, totalpercentage);


                   if(pagetotal==currentpagenumber){
                       bundle.putString("TEST", currentpage);
                       Intent intent = new Intent(UserFragment.this.getActivity(), DisplayAverageActivity.class);                  
                       bundle.putInt("numberofforms", getArguments().getInt("page_position")); 
                       bundle.putSparseParcelableArray("Questions",questions);
                       intent.putExtras(bundle);
                       startActivity(intent);

                   }


               }
    });
        return rootView;

    }
//this is an error, on every creation of UserFragment, it basically creates a new questions array.
    // This results in only the the existance of (questions.get(lastpage).hello).
       SparseArray<Question> questions = new SparseArray<Question>();
    public void saveData(Question quest, int pagenumber){
           questions.put(pagenumber, quest);

    }



}
```

I cannot think of a way to do this (correctly) without defining a new SparseArray called question, every time. So basically when I try to access this, of course the, only iteration that does not give me a null pointer is the last. When I access it like this for example: String markk = questions.get(totalasses-1).mark; only totalasses-1 works. So I would really appreciate it, if anybody could assist me on a solution to my problem, how do I define the array, in let's say FirstFragment.java (or somewhere external to UserFragment) so that it only creates the SparseArray once, and then just fills each entry with the Question form from the corresponding view pager form?

If you could, please include some coded examples, and some explanation as I am a beginner, and I do want to learn, as well as finding a solution!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways you could approach this.

You could do it the lazy way and just make your SparseArray a static variable by adding the static keyword (i.e `static SparseArray<Question> questions = new SparseArray<Question>();`)

or you could use [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and store the sparse array in the `savedInstanceState` parameter

to fetch the array

```
SparseArray<Question> questions = savedInstanceState.getSparseParcelableArray("questions");
```

to store it

```
savedInstanceState.putSparseParcelableArray("questions", questions);
```

**However**, your `Question` class is going to need to implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) (Edit: Never mind, I see you already do)

The third is way is by making a reference to a class that only has a single instance and storing the `questions` variable inside that class, but you are not providing any other classes in your post, so I don't see where you would place this.

Comment: Oh so, how does the "static" declaration solve my issue? Could you explain? And with the second suggested solution, is this basically storing it to the savedInstanceState inside the UserFragment. So each time I call it, I extract the array, add to it, store it, and then repeat until? What about the first instance when the UserFragment is first created, how does that work? Thank you for your help :) I just need a little more understanding!

Comment: I should have provided a link on what the static keyword does, my mistake. Making your variable static basically makes it global for every instance of UserFragment. So basically, it belongs to every UserFragment and the data will be persistent in each instance.

Comment: How does that fix it, if I'm always creating a new instance of it, over every instance of UserFragment?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the questions sparse array is your raw data which should not change between activities.

If this is the case, then you have several options. One of my favourite options is to use a Singleton implementation to save the questions.

Create a new class, and define it as a singleton (private constructor, static private instance of the class, static public "getInstance()" method which initializes the instance if it's null and returns the object).

Place your sparse array there, and then you can be sure that it will persist throughout any activity's or fragment's life cycle.

Edit: Here's an example for a singleton which would do what you need.

```
public class GlobalData 
{

    private static GlobalData instance;

    private SparseArray<Question> _data;

    public static GlobalData getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new GlobalData();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private GlobalData()
    {
         _data = new SparseArray<Question>();
    }

    public SparseArray<Question> getData()
    {
        return _data;
    }
}
```

This should get you started.

Comment: The Question object is my raw data, and I am trying to build the SparseArray questions, which, yes is my raw data and I need to keep it! Could you please elaborate on how I could do this with a bit more detail (and or code), as I don't know how I would be able to do this! Thank you for your response :)

Comment: if this answers your question, feel free to up vote / accept. thanks!

Comment: I used the static solution above. But i will up vote :) when I get over 15 rep!